# Transactional NTFS - wait for CommitTransaction

Tags: windows, transactions, ntfs

I'm using Transactional NTFS to atomize multiple writes to several files.
The problem is that after commit, I may not be able to reopen a file,
perhaps because of a racing condition.

The sequence of events is :

1. NTFS transaction is created with `CreateTransaction`
2. Files are opened with `CreateFileTransacted`
3. Writes are done to the files
4. Files are closed with `CloseHandle`
5. Transaction is committed with `CommitTransaction`
6. Files are reopened with `CreateFile` for read/write

The last step sometimes fails with error code 3 :
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND - The system cannot find the path specified.
When re-executing the program, the file is then found.
This happens rarely, but in a completely random manner, meaning not always
when reopening the same file.

My theory is that if terminating the transaction by Windows takes a long
time, the files are not available for opening in read/write mode until
the transaction terminates. My program then fails when trying to open
my own files in non-transaction mode.

I think that to avoid this problem, I need to wait for the transaction
to complete before reopening the files.
However, I have not found any documented method for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No clever answers, so I had to implement my own dummy one :

If an I/O error happens on opening a file that was just closed,
the solution was to loop on opening several times while in-between calling
Sleep() to release the CPU, before deciding that a catastrophic error had occurred.

Dummy solution, but it solved the problem.